# Tailwind CSS transition on load

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to add an opacity transition on a div. It should start at opacity 0 and once it is visible on the screen it should fade in slowly, to the maximum opacity.

Here is my code:

```
<div className="transition-opacity ease-in-out opacity-0 <STATE>:opacity-100 duration-300"> ... </div>
```

However, I do not know what state to use for my purpose. What should I replace the STATE from above with? Or is it not the right approach?

Comment: I would look at using IntersectionObserver to detect when it is in view, and then with some javascript, remove the `opacity-0` class, and add `opacity-100`.

Answer (score 2):

Think you are on the right track with this, you'd just need to toggle a class upon load:

```js
const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

handleLoad = () => {
  setLoaded(true);
}

componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('load', this.handleLoad);
}
```

```html
<div className={`${loaded ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-0"}`>
```

If there's a more elegant solution to this from a React expert, would be good to know :)

Comment: And if you need to check visibility in the viewport I would suggest something like https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer

Answer (score -1):

try adding this

```
<div className="duration-75">
```

...

Comment: please explain what your solution does ?